# i am practice on a small contact form ,i want to render a full view with user name in it

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, ejs

controller

the validation is working fine.
but the "sent" view not is rendering

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index")
})
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const { error } = formValidation(req.body);
  if (error) {
    return res.send({message: error.details[0].message});
  };
  res.render('sent', { name: req.body.name });
})
```

ajax script.

I used jQuery ajax so that user retain the input, if there any invalid inputs.

And displayed the error in a element.

Am i putting the rendered view into the element, is that the problem?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#submit").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let formData = {
      name: $("#fname")[0].value,
      email: $("#email")[0].value,
      subject: $("#subject")[0].value,
      message: $("#message")[0].value,
    };

    $.ajax({
      url: "/",
      data: formData,
      dataType: "json",
      method: "POST",
      success: function (data) {
        $("#msg").html(data.message);  
      },
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: open netwrorktab of dev-console of your brawser. click on your request , and select response tab, you will see how your data is structured . because  data.message probably is only data or something else

Comment: Are you really using res.render to output JSON?!

Comment: @Quentin       how to render 'sent' view if data.message is empty